# PIL saving image asyncronously?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am processing an image progressively by cropping it multiple times inside a loop. Before each crop I save the new base image and then I proceed to the next operation. Lately I tried to to this while testing with cypress, so operations are much faster and by the time the next crop is requested sometimes the original file has not been saved yet. (Used
`subprocess.run(['ls', fromPage_imagePath], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout` before cropping and noticed that the file was not there at the time of the next loop)

The problem looked addressable but instead I've been struggling with this at least a couple of hours.
I first tried to `flush` the image, i.e.

```
img.save(toPage_imagePath)
img.flush()
os.fsync(img)
```

but then realized that a PIL object is not a file. I then followed recommendations from [this post](https://discourse.techart.online/t/pil-wait-for-image-save/3994) and tried using a file object for saving the image, i.e.

1:

```
with open(toPage_imagePath, 'wb') as out_file:
    img.save(out_file, 'PNG')
    out_file.flush()
    os.fsync(out_file)
```

and 2:

```
out_file = open(toPage_imagePath, 'wb')
img.save(out_file, 'PNG')
out_file.flush()
os.fsync(out_file)
out_file.close()
```

and finally tried even the `time` waiting option suggested in there, or:

```
img.save(toPage_imagePath)

noinfinite = 0
while noinfinite < 25:
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.path.isfile(toPage_imagePath):
        print('file found')
        break
    noinfinite += 1
```

but my code seems to swiftly ignore my attempts and jumps to the next loop. What I am missing here? I need a way to reliably pause the code until the PIL image is saved.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do please? What are *cypress so operations"*?

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Probably it would have been clearer with a comma in the sentence? Also this would help and just added it: I need a way to reliably pause the code until the PIL image is saved.

Comment: I'm still having trouble understanding the problem. What is `cypress` please? Do you have a **simple, complete** piece of code, with `import` statements that demonstrates the issue, please?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought [Cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) was widely known: it's a test suite that allows you to do integration and end to end testing. It's like having a macro that performs all user interactions you tell it to do as fast as it can. Let me see if I can simplify the code and post it. It spans through a bunch of modules and across Python, Django and JS so am not sure I can come up with something clear but will try. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Pfft, I realized what's wrong here. It's not a Python problem, it's an issue that comes from the front end requesting the crop multiple times and the back end not having finished processing the previous request when the new one gets in. The solution is to package the request appropriately in the front end so that the server can handle it entirely and manage it in its own time.  Thanks for forcing me to analyze the problem further @MarkSetchell